# How to calculate sum of all rows with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

Below is my table  code with `Add New` button. Onclick `Add New` 
button new row will create. In picture you can see this. User will
input debit and credit values at the end all debit values should be
calculate and sum should be display and same for the credit value. I
am using jQuery to create new row:

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#add, .check ").click(function() {
      $('#datatable-buttons tbody>tr:last')
      .clone(true)
      .insertAfter('#datatable-buttons tbody>tr:last').find('input').each(function(){
      $(this).val('');
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Html table code:

```
<table id="datatable-buttons"  class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
    <thead>
      <tr class="headings">
        <th>
          <input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat">
        </th>
        <th class="column-title">Account</th>
        <th class="column-title">Debits</th>
        <th class="column-title">Credits</th>
        <th class="column-title">Description</th> 
        <th class="column-title">Name</th>                          
        <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr">Action</span>
        </th>
        <th class="bulk-actions" colspan="7">
          <a class="antoo" style="color:#fff; font-weight:500;">Bulk Actions ( <span class="action-cnt"> </span> ) <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>                                
    <tbody>
      <tr class="even pointer">
        <td class="a-center ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="flat" name="table_records">
        </td>                                    
        <td class=" "><select class="form-control" name="journalname">
          <option>Choose option</option>                   
          <?php
          $sql = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT * FROM `chartofaccounts`');
          while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) 
            {?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row1["name"];?>"><?php echo $row1["name"];?></option>
          <?php  }?>
        </select></td>
        <td class=""><input class="form-control" type="text" name="debit" ></td>
        <td class=" "><input class="form-control" type="text" name="credit"></td>
        <td class=" "><input class="form-control" type="text" name="descc"></td> 
        <td class=" "><input class="form-control" type="text" name="name"></td>        
        <td class=" last"><a href="#">View</a>
        </td>
      </tr>                           
    </tbody>                           
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="add">Add New</button>
```

Below image will give you clear understanding:

[image]

Comment: 1. search your title in Google 2. delete question since it is a duplicate 3. if not a duplicate (unlikely) click the `<>` button and create a [mcve] WITHOUT PHP  and explain why it was not a duplicate

Comment: you never said what the problem is; you only included a screenshot but not describing what difficulties you're having.

Comment: it not duplicate. all other examples not having jquery like mine. and that's a problem i add `add new` script. and i am stuck to add values and display sum

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i dont think so bro. if u read my question carefully you will get to know what problem i am facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made you a simple example of how to calculate the sum from the input fields.

check snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/822vbozw/14/)

add numbers to the 3 inputs, and then click on `View` , it will get the sum of the 3 input values.

```js
var input = $("input"),
    button = $("td.last a")

$(button).click(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(input).each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
   $(this).html(sum)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input>
    </td>
    <td class=" last"><a href="#">View</a>
  </tr>
</table>
```